# compare between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a course table and a course  due dates table like this

```
course_id | course_name 
1           A
2           B 

due_id | start_date | end_date    course_id 
1        2011-02-01   2011-02-28  1
2        2011-03-01   2011-03-15  1
```

now what i am trying to do from last tow day that write a query or code that will show a course name with current date session.for example if current date is betwen start and end date course should come like this and if its in next date session it should come with next due_id

```
course_id | course_name | due_id
1           A           | 1
```

if this database structure is wrong for this please let me know

thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT course.course_name, due_dates.course_id, due_id
FROM course
INNER JOIN due_dates ON course.course_id = due_dates.course_id
WHERE now() BETWEEN start_date and end_date;
```